# find control in panel in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had Datalist and inside it panel and inside panel label and I want to find label inside panel inside datalist.I did my code but it didnot work well

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {

```
    Label LblHead = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    string LanguageID = Globals.GetSuitableLanguage(Page);

    if (LanguageID == "ar")
    {
        LblHead.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "hed_logo2");
    }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, tested on my local:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Panel panel1 = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;   //assume your panel name is Panel1
        if (panel1 != null)
        {
            Label LblHead = panel1.FindControl("LblHead") as Label;
            if (LblHead != null)
            {
                string LanguageID = Globals.GetSuitableLanguage(Page);
                if (LanguageID == "ar")
                {
                    LblHead.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "hed_logo2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add following check,

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
                 e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    // your code here
}
```